# map scala class on json reads method

Tags: json, scala

Hello I'm trying to implement this method :

```
override def reads(json: JsValue): JsSuccess[Data] = JsSuccess( new Data(
      (json \ "title").as[String], 
      (json \ "User").as[User]
      ) 
)
```

but then when I try to use it with

```
val b = jsonData.as[Data]
```

it gives me an error:

```
models.Data$dataFormat$.reads(Data.scala:73)
```

and line 73 is `(json \ "User").as[User]`

Can anybody help me, because I can't get what is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: It's very difficult to try to answer a question like this when you haven't included information like what the error was or what Json library you're using here. Please update with these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming User is a case class, have you defined a implicit reads function for User so that a User's deserialization can be done?

Have a look at: this excellent explanation of [json handling in play](http://mandubian.com/2012/09/08/unveiling-play-2-dot-1-json-api-part1-jspath-reads-combinators/), which should be applicable for any jackson-based library.